How much payload could Falcon 9 send to a 100km lunar orbit?
SpaceX has said that Falcon 9 can send 4020 kilograms to Mars. However, I can't seem to find the payload capacity to lunar orbit. So, how much payload can Falcon 9 send to a lunar orbit at an altitude of, say, 100 kilometers?
I would be interested in both expendable and drone ship landing configurations. Based on this answer, Falcon 9 cannot send anything even to Geostationary Orbit with an RTLS landing, so unless I'm missing something I don't think it could do so for the lunar surface either.

IIRC the total dV to get on an intercept with Mars is only about 7% more than to get on an intercept with the Moon, and GEO costs a bit more than a moon intercept (but that's a collision course and you'd need to spend some of that mass on fuel to go into lunar orbit or land or whatever).

Do you mean to TLI (trans lunar injection) or the lunar surface? Falcon 9 second stage doesn't have the ability to land on the lunar surface, so it's payload there is 0kg without a lander.

@DarthPseudonym I did write lunar surface…why can’t F9 second stage go there

The linked answer about geostationary orbit is wrong on multiple counts-- both the delta-v and Isp numbers are incorrect. Falcon 9 can probably carry positive payload to GEO in RTLS configuration.

@lirtosiast Maybe add that as a comment to the answer (and what numbers you think are correct, and a source)

@Starship I think you're talking to Barry not me, but a lander is a specific piece of technology, you can't just point any random rocket down and use it to land on. For one thing, a lot of rockets either can't restart once they shut down, or have a specific number of restarts available (usually just 1-2), and don't throttle very well.  A lander generally needs a wide range of throttle settings and the ability to relight repeatedly (which hypergolics answer pretty effectively), in addition to the basics like landing legs.

Like, to me, "Payload to the lunar surface" means "payload to lunar intercept" and it's the payload's job to be able to manage a landing (or not, like the Russian Luna missions that just slammed into the moon at high speed); the weight cost of landing systems counts against that 4000-whatever kg to intercept and doesn't use any of the lifter's systems.  Fairly sure that's what the 4000 kg to mars means, it's to mars intercept, not to-surface.

@DarthPseudonym Yes oops I was. The SpaceX second can restart at least 3 times (I've occasionally seen an SES-3 burn, and SpaceX also deorbits their spacecraft which takes another burn). Obviously it would need landing legs but I would imagine that's relatively little weight.

SpaceX doesn't use discrete relights, they use TEA-TEB igniter jets that are basically little flamethrowers, and how many relights they can get is determined by how long it takes to get the engine started each time. I believe they only expect to manage two starts, though that's probably something only a mission planner could speak to. I'm not familiar with an orbital insertion plan that requires the upper stage to start three times, but I can't swear it didn't happen.  Still, I stand by my statement that a lander needs to be purpose built and you can't just kludge one together from parts.

@DarthPseudonym I have seen an SES-3 before so that's a least 4 relights (those 3+1 deorbit burn). Anyways, changed the question to lunar orbit.

For what it's worth, Falcon 9 absolutely can loft to GEO and still do an RTLS. Did it on 11/11/2024 with KoreaSat 6a. The weight limit is low (~3.5 ton), but it's possible.
